# chip is not found in the working and built in folder- Nand2tetris

Tags: nand2tetris

why does the hardware simulator respond this way [error code: chip is not found in the working and built in folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/276IL.png) while trying to load the chip. I get similar errors with Mux4way16 and Mux8way16. Does someone know where the problem might be? thanks!

```
CHIP Mux{
    IN a, b, sel;
    OUT out;

    PARTS:
    // output depending on sel=> and(sel,a)= sela, and(not(sel),b)= sel'b => or(and(sel,a), and(not(sel),b))= sela + (sel)'b
    Not(in= sel,out= notsel); 
    Nand(a= notsel,b= a,out= out1);
    Nand(a= sel,b= b,out= out2);
    Nand(a= out1,b= out2,out= out);
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire .hdl file you are trying to load. It is likely that the error is somewhere in the file, probably a typo in one of the components you are attempting to use or a syntax error that is getting the simulator confused.

Comment: hi, I added a picture of the content in the .hdl file. It does not seem to be any syntax irregularity... Ive had the same issues also with the half adder now it seems. Maybe it could be an issue with copy/paste from notes?

Comment: In future, please post code as inline text, it makes it much easier for people to try and reproduce your problem. Also, by replacing the initial image, your question no longer has the information needed for a new responder to give you any advice. At all times, your question needs to have all of the information needed for people to try and help you (and for others with a similar problem to find the question and the answer). See below for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to run correctly on my computer. It is likely that for some reason, your And, Or or Not implementations are not being found by the hardware simulator (or do not compile properly).

You may also wish to recode your Mux implementation using only Not and Nand (or just Nand), it requires fewer gates.

Comment: updated code is using only Nand and not. shouldn't be an issue now. strange.